# Extract specific data from multiple text files in a directory

Tags: perl

This is my first program in perl.
I have more than 1000 files and I want to extract specific data from a file. The structure of all the files are same.
Its really difficult to open every file and then copy a specific data,

How can I achieve this using perl.

The structure looks like this.

```
    LensMode=Normal
    MicronMarker=500
    DataDisplayCombine=1
    Voltage=0 Volt
    PixelSize=1.586612
```

I want to extract MicronMarker and PixelSize from each file.
Any help in the right direction is appreciated.

the location is D:\Files\Folder1

Comment: What do you want to do with these values once you have extracted them

Comment: It doesn't look like you've made an attempt to solve this problem yourself. You'll usually get better feedback if you at least make an effort, rather than just asking people to come up with the entire solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Use `glob` to read the directory

```
while (my $files = glob(" D:\Files\Folder1\*"))
{
    open my $handler,"<","$files";
    my @extract = grep{ m/^(MicronMarker|PixelSize)/g} <$handler>;  
    print @extract;
}
```

Extract the word from a file using the `while loop` by `opendir`.

```
opendir(my $dir, " D:\Files\Folder1");

while (my $ech = readdir($dir))
{
    open my $handler,"<","test/$ech";
    while(my $l = <$handler>)
    {
        if($l =~m/^(?:MicronMarker|PixelSize)/g)
        {
            print "$l";

        }

    }
    close ($handler);
}
```

This is easy way to extract a words from a file using `grep`

```
while (my $ech = readdir($dir))
{
    open my $handler,"<","test/$ech";
    my @extract = grep{ m/^(MicronMarker|PixelSize)/g} <$handler>;
    print @extract;
    close($handler);
}
```